# Undefined reference to a method that is defined, declaration in header and source match

Tags: c++, function, undefined

I have the following method declared in the public area of a class like that:

In the header file:

```
class EntityManager
{
    public:
        ...
        template <typename ComponentType>
        bool addComponentToEntity(const Entity in_Entity, const shared_ptr<ComponentType> in_ComponentInstance);
        ...
}
```

In the source file:

```
template <typename ComponentType>
bool EntityManager::addComponentToEntity(const Entity in_Entity, const shared_ptr<ComponentType> in_ComponentInstance)
{
    ...
}
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
Entity l_Entity = 1;
shared_ptr<TestComponent> l_TestComponent(new TestComponent());
EntityManager* l_EntityManager = new EntityManager();

l_EntityManager->addComponentToEntity<TestComponent>(l_Entity, l_TestComponent);
```

This results in the compiler complaining:

```
undefined reference to `bool EntityManager::addComponentToEntity<TestComponent>(unsigned long, boost::shared_ptr<TestComponent>)'|
```

I am aware that this is probably because I am not very experienced in C++ programming, but I can't see a reason why the function is undefined. I ommitted some other code that calls other functions of the EntityManager class and that works perfectly well.

I also tried rewriting the function with regular pointers, references and even passes by value with the same result.

Comment: Is the code where you _use_ this function in the same file as the definition of the function (i.e. the file you called 'source file')?

Comment: Does it work if you add `const` to the declaration of `l_TestComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template methods/functions must be defined in the header itself (unless the method's class itself is defined in a source file). This is also the case for all methods of a template class (even if the methods themselves aren't template methods).

Most people don't even bother defining them below the class definition, they just define them inline inside the class:

```
class EntityManager 
{ 
    public: 
        ... 
        template <typename ComponentType> 
        bool addComponentToEntity(const Entity in_Entity, const shared_ptr<ComponentType> in_ComponentInstance)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
```

}

Comment: That fixed it. I was very unaware of this restriction, seems quite ugly that the implementation code has to be in the header.